Why do I get invalid_refresh_token error when trying to refresh the token for Slack?
I am developing something like Zapier/N8N, in which user can come and create Slack integration and then installs the app in his workspace. Tokens are generated and I stored them in the DB.
Earlier I was using long-lived bot and user tokens. I wanted to have the tokens refreshed. I am following this: https://api.slack.com/authentication/rotation
Note: I have different bot/user scopes in my App home page and I request different scopes from my code when generating OAuth URL (Which is prompted to the User. Is this okay?
Below Screen:

I added the code to generate refresh token, access token, expires_in. Now suppose, User comes and he creates a new integration, fresh set of access_token and refresh_token along with expiry are generated. Now in my UI, if user performs some action like Create channel/send msg to user. I check by comparing the current time and the expires_in, if the current time is more than I perform refresh using oauth.v2.access.
Is it correct that for every user, I have unique set of access and refresh tokens? Which are different from the ones listed in the Slack App home page
How did I test this on my local that it works?
I manually updated my expires_in to be 1 day back, so automatically refresh was done.
Now on my server(Deployed. code),
I created an integration(access_token, refresh_token were generated) and did not perform any action for 12 hours. Then I tried to do some Slack action, I got below error:
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "invalid_refresh_token"
}

I read the same from here also:
https://forums.slackcommunity.com/s/question/0D5Hq00009OgLQgKAN/what-is-the-expiration-time-for-refresh-token-?language=en_US
So is it correct behavior that refresh_token is also expired in 12 hours so it is mandatory for the user to ask for refresh in 12 hour limit from where the access token was generated. Any attempt to refresh it after the 12 hours period with the refresh token will result in error?
I also read that a schedule task should be created. But imagine I have millions of slack integrations from users so I can't have a watch on them and update them when the expiry time is near.
Is my understanding correct? If refresh token is also expired then what is the use of keeping check on access_token? Here my user did not do any action in 12 hours (from when the access_token was generated and till access_token got expired), then my user tries to do some action.
Is my refresh_token becoming invalid due to some other reason?
I am occasionally getting token_revoked error as well.
I see bot and user access and refresh token in App home page along with their expiration time, Do I get token_expired error, when they are expired (on the App home)?
My refresh tokens are getting expired in 3-4 hours.
Please help. It is very confusing.
